# openMVG + MeshLab produces strange results

Tags: c++, photogrammetry, meshlab

I'm trying to use OpenMVG ( imagine.enpc.fr/~moulonp/openMVG/ ) to produce a point cloud from a series of photos. The clould appears more or less fine...

[image]

But then I run the surface reconstruction poisson in meshlab, here's that happens

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I can only guess but it looks like the camera centers (green) are still in your point cloud file! Those are the last values in FinalColorized.ply. Try to remove those vertices. You can manually edit the .ply file: remove those values and adjust the number of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you exported the results of openMVG to PMVS/CMVS to generate dense point cloud? It looks fine, but just the sparse cloud, maybe it's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Richard Richard's comment is correct.  The output from openMVG is a sparse point cloud and the camera poses.

This information can be used to construct a dense point cloud using another algorithm.  OpenMVS or PVMS/CVMS are open source projects that can do the dense cloud reconstruction.  OpenMVS can also build a mesh and texture that mesh.